# Laravel - set session from form input

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-views, laravel-session

I cannot display session value in my view. I only want to display it to see if it's correctly set inside the controller. Is it correctly set in controller? How can I check?
I have this in view:

```
<div class="panel panel-success">
                <form action="{{ route('get_table') }}" method="POST">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    @foreach($tables as  $data)                   
                    <button type="submit" name="tables" class="btn btn-primary" value="{{ $data->id }}">
                        {{$data->name }}
                    </button>
                    @endforeach
                </form>
                {{ Session::get('table_id') }}
            </div>
```

This in ListController:

```
public function index() {
    $tables = DB::table('tables')->get();
    return view('welcome', compact('tables'));
}

public function getTable(Request $request) {
    $table_id = $request->get('tables');
    $request->session()->put('table_id', $table_id);
}
```

And this in web.php routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'ListController@index')->name('get_table');
Route::post('/', 'ListController@getTable');
```

I even tried

```
public function getTable(Request $request) {
    $request->session()->put('table_id', '1234');
}
```

Nothing shows up in the view at  `{{ Session::get('table_id') }}`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession' isset in your middlewares?

Comment: It is in `protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` in my kernel.php

Comment: Your code for setting and retrieving a session variable is correct, tried it. Maybe you check setting in the ìndex()`function of your controller first.

Comment: the index function works fine because in my view I can see all the foreach buttons correctly. I don't know how to check the getTable function. That is why I put `{{ Session::get('table_id') }}` in the view to check if the session is set after I submit a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public function getTable(Request $request) {
    $table_id = $request->get('tables');
    return redirect()->back()->with('table_id',$table_id);
}
```

if you want to redirect to specific route then:

```
public function getTable(Request $request) {
    $table_id = $request->get('tables');
    return redirect()->route('RouteName')->with('table_id',$table_id);
}
```

and then in view:

```
  @if(Session::has('table_id'))

      {{ Session::get('table_id') }}

  @endif
```

Hope you got your answer

Comment: But how do I put table_id in the session?

Comment: return redirect()->route('RouteName')->with('table_id',$table_id);
with() method save session ,is is also called as session_flash

Comment: I tried with  `return redirect()->back()->with('table_id',$table_id);` but in the view I can only see the buttons, I can't see `{{ Session::get('table_id') }}` value no matter what button I click. I read documentation on session_flash, I need the data to be stored longer in the session not only for this request.

Comment: then try this:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

Session::put('table_id',$table_id);

Comment: Same issue, I don't know what I am doing wrong, do you have any suggestions on how should check where the code fails? Thank you

Comment: Sure, but the app is on a local wamp on my pc, it is not accesible from internet only local network. How can I give you access?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174792/discussion-between-salman-zafar-and-victordb).